Why the pre-trained VGG model does not accept images with single or more than three channels
I am trying to modify the VGG model to input more than 3 channels.
vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
vgg_config = vgg_model.get_config()

# Change the input shape to new desired shape
h, w, c = 1024, 1024, 9
vgg_config["layers"][0]["config"]["batch_input_shape"] = (None, h, w, c)

#Create new model with the updated configuration
vgg_updated = Model.from_config(vgg_config)

Error:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "block1_conv1" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3, but received input with shape (None, 1024, 1024, 9)

I borrowed this code from here, which seems to work for them. What is missing in these lines?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
